# Inserting/Deleting data from a nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am using react.js to manage a list of nested "items". My object looks like so:

```
const items = [
  {
    _id: 0,
    content: 'Item 1 something',
    note: 'Some note for item 1'
  },
  {
    _id: 5,
    content: 'Item 1.1 something',
    note: 'Some note for item 1.1'
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    content: 'Item 2 something',
    note: 'Some note for item 2',
    subItems: [
      {
        _id: 2,
        parent_id: 1,
        content: 'Sub Item 1 something',
        subItems: [{
          _id: 3,
          parent_id: 2,
          content: 'Sub Sub Item 4'
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Provided I only have the _id for any item. How can I insert another item before/after the item I have an _id for, at any level (top-level or nested) and delete an item at any level provided I only have an _id for.

Since I'm using react.js, how do I do those operations in an immutable way?

Comment: lets say _id=1 then what you want to delete ?? complete object with its subitems also or what ?? update ur ques with result if _id=1.

Comment: Yes, complete object, with subitems if _id=1. Similarly how to I insert an item before _id=2 and after _id=2 if I want to do so and in an immutable way. If this were an array, I'd use the index, splice stuff, but how do I go about doing this for an object?

Answer (score 1):

You could create recursive function for this. First you can clone your array with `JSON parse/stringify` which is not best method but will work in this case and then you can use `for...in` loop to loop data and if id is found in some object it will add new item to the start of that array using `unshift`.

```js
const items = [{"_id":0,"content":"Item 1 something","note":"Some note for item 1"},{"_id":5,"content":"Item 1.1 something","note":"Some note for item 1.1"},{"_id":1,"content":"Item 2 something","note":"Some note for item 2","subItems":[{"_id":2,"parent_id":1,"content":"Sub Item 1 something","subItems":[{"_id":3,"parent_id":2,"content":"Sub Sub Item 4"}]}]}]  

function addItem(data, item, id) {
  data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

  function inner(data, item, id, parent) {
    for (var i in data) {
      if (data[i]._id == id) {
        parent.unshift(item)
        return;
      }
      if (data[i] && data[i].hasOwnProperty('subItems')) {
        inner(data[i].subItems, item, id, data[i].subItems)
      }
    }
  }
  inner(data, item, id, data)
  return data;
}

var newItem = {
  name: 'Lorem',
  age: 20
}
console.log(addItem(items, newItem, 3))
```

If you want to delete instead of add item you can use `splice(i, 1)`

```js
const items = [{"_id":0,"content":"Item 1 something","note":"Some note for item 1"},{"_id":5,"content":"Item 1.1 something","note":"Some note for item 1.1"},{"_id":1,"content":"Item 2 something","note":"Some note for item 2","subItems":[{"_id":2,"parent_id":1,"content":"Sub Item 1 something","subItems":[{"_id":3,"parent_id":2,"content":"Sub Sub Item 4"}]}]}]  


function addItem(data, item, id) {
  data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))

  function inner(data, item, id, parent) {
    for (var i in data) {
      if (data[i]._id == id) {
        data.splice(i, 1)
        return
      }
      if (data[i] && data[i].hasOwnProperty('subItems')) {
        inner(data[i].subItems, item, id, data[i].subItems)
      }
    }
  }
  inner(data, item, id, data)
  return data;
}

console.log(addItem(items, '', 2))
```

Comment: thank you! If I'm not wrong, unshift only insert at the beginning of the  array. From the result of your insert above, what if I want to add an item between the "lorem" item you just added and the item with _id 3 - how do I proceed?

Comment: In that case you can use another approach, so you can add one more parameter to your function which is `index` where you are going to insert new item, so you get something like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1514/. Note that this function doesn't change original data but returns new data so you need to use that new data if you want to run again function on it.